# How to send scan code >255 from hid ble keyboard from esp32 over gatt?

Tags: c, embedded, hid, esp32, esp-idf

I'm using esp-32 esp-idf HID library (https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/bluetooth/ble_hid_device_demo) to make a custom keyboard that sends scan codes to an android device. I need  to send scan code = 310, that contains two bytes of data.

I have a device that requires ble hid keyboard's button's scan code = 310[dec]. As I tried to send this code as uint8_t key_vaule[], as it's used in ble_hid_demo_main.c in ble_hid_device_demo project, the device recieved another scan code, it was truncated from 000 0001 0011 0110 [310dec] to 0011 0110 [155dec]. I suppose it happens because of the 8 bit size of the transferred variables instead of 16 bit. Modyfying the libraries from uint8_t size to uint16_t gave nothing, the result was still truncated. Is there a way to send a two-byte code instead of 1 byte?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider improving the formatting of your question (see also here https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). This will help others understanding the issue you are facing.

Comment: Side note: the truncated code is not decimal `155`. The binary `0011 0110` is decimal `54`. Decimal `155` is half of the required `310` so is there something you have overlooked?

Comment: It would be far easier to advise if you posted your code.  Links to off-site material is likely to go out of date, and it is your code that is failing, so to fix it you have to show it.  Much easier and more accurate the _describing_ it!

Comment: It seems this was an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  Perhaps you should have simply asked, _"Using this [esp-32 esp-idf HID library](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/bluetooth/ble_hid_device_demo), how can I issue the key combination `CTRL+,`?_".  Then perhaps presented your failed attempts in code (_not_ descriptions of code).  Instead you have devised a flawed solution and asked about the problem with the solution and obscuring what you actually want to achieve.  Something to think about next time you post perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

[HID scan codes](https://gist.github.com/MightyPork/6da26e382a7ad91b5496ee55fdc73db2) are always 8 bit.  Key combinations such as left-<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd><,</kbd> in this case, are a sequence of a "key modifier" (0x01 for left-<kbd>CTRL</kbd>) and a key code (0x36 for <kbd><,</kbd>).

Whist 0x0136 happens to be 310<sub>10</sub>, it is a mistake to think of multi-byte scan codes sequences as a single integer rather that a byte sequence for a number of reasons:

- the integer byte for the machine architecture may not match that defined for HID code sequences,
- In an HID keyboard report, it there is a single key modifier byte and up to six key codes - for combinations of up-to 6 regular keys and eight modifier bits for shift, alt, ctrl etc. combinations pressed simultaneously,
- In an HID keyboard report there is a "reserved" byte between the modifier and the first key code in any case, so the 0x01 and 0x36 are not contiguous in any case regardless of the machine byte order.

In the case of [HID scan codes](https://gist.github.com/MightyPork/6da26e382a7ad91b5496ee55fdc73db2), your 310<sub>10</sub> is in fact two bytes 0x01 and 0x36 (in hexadecimal). When talking about byte sequences it is more natural to use hexadecimal notation - especially in teh case ofthe modifier which is a bit-mask for multiple shift/ctrl etc. keys. The 0x36 represents the key <kbd><,</kbd>, and the 0x01 is a key modifier for left-<kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

If your value 310 was truncated when you assigned it to a 16 bit integer most likely you passed it as a single value to an interface that expected a `uint8_t`.  But as explained above, sending a 16bit integer is not correct in any case.

Rather then sending 0x0136 or 310<sub>10</sub> you need to send a byte sequence to form a valid keyboard report as described by your device's  keyboard report descriptor.  In an HID keyboard report, the first byte is the "modifier mask" (0x01/left-<kbd>CTRL</kbd>), the second byte is reserved, then there are up-to 6 key codes (allowing multi-key combinations) the actual number of keys supported and therefore length of the report is defined by the report descriptor.

Looking at the API in the HID demo you linked however it is clear that all that is abstracted away and it seems that what you actually need to do is something like:

```
uint8_t key = HID_KEY_COMMA ;
esp_hidd_send_keyboard_value( hid_conn_id, LEFT_CONTROL_KEY_MASK, &key, 1 ) ;
```

Note that the modifier is a bit-mask allowing any combination of modifier keys, such as `LEFT_CONTROL_KEY_MASK|RIGHT_CONTROL_KEY_MASK`.  The HID would use this to indicate multiple shifts, but a receiver might use it to allow either the left or right keys without distinction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried your method, but ut didn't work. As I tried to send HID_KEY_COMMA with ctrl modifyer my device still recieved it as it was comma, so the scan code still was 54. I can see it in a key event logger on my android devide. I also received an andice from esp to modify report map in [link](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/bluetooth/ble_hid_device_demo/main/hid_device_le_prf.c) but i don't understand the issue of modifying it, where should i change the value of my report size so that i could send two byte value (they said it's possible btw)

Comment: @OPyshkin : You are not helping yourself by not posting your code as I have suggested - it leaves a lot of guesswork.  You are clearly under some misconception regarding scancodes - the information in my answer is from the HID device specification.  Moreover, clearly the ESP HIDD API uses a 8 bit type for the scan code.  The call I proposed _does_ specify two bytes in an HID report.  The problem is likely to be in the reading rather then the sending, or in your interpretation of what you are reading.  Rather than commenting on this answer, put your evidence in the question.

Comment: @OPyshkin , futher if you do not understand the advice from ESP support, ask them to clarify or ask another question - or add that advice to your question so we can all benefit.

Comment: sorry for the delay. That's reply from esp. [link](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/3539) To clarify, the main aim of the project is to connect ble hid button to an android-based data harvesting terminal, so by pressing the button we would be able to start the scanner. The scancode that is binded to the terminal's scan button is 310. So I can't clearly understand where my problem is. About the code, i haven't changed it so much, so it's almost similar to the esp's sample project.

Comment: About esp's advice, they suggested modifying hid report map, [link](https://pastebin.com/abyG16Zh) I dont clearly understand wich parametrs i should change. I tried changing log max and usage max at Key arrays section, so it gave no result.